# Updating to Meteor 0.6.5, What version of Nodejs do you need, and can you still use Meteorite?

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteorite

I would like to know what version of Nodejs you need to run Meteor 0.6.5?

Also can you still use Meteorite?

Comment: [Meteorite's documentation](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite#readme) doesn't give any indications that it doesn't support Meteor 0.6.5. The only compatibility issue mentioned is that it lacks [Windows support](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite#notes).

Answer (score 1):

You should try to Google first.

> Node 0.8.24

Reference: [Meteor Change Log](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md)

Comment: Why would node version Meteor depends on relate to the question of Meteorite, which is mostly a wrapper and packages fetcher? Am I missing something?

Comment: Ask Meteor . We aren't the developers of Meteor.

Comment: OK, that's what I am trying to say: Meteor doesn't depend on version of node you have installed as it ships with its own binary of node, npm, mongod and friends. Meteorite, however, is a community project. Since Meteorite is a npm module it does depend on your version of node you have installed in your system, but it has nothing to do with Meteor latest change log.

Comment: I did try google first.  That's how I got to this page.